# Problem with comparing two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

What I am trying to do.
I want to confirm that **IvanIvanov** from column A corresponds to **IvanIvanov**_32_y1988_12 from column B. I do not know how to extract **IvanIvanov** from column B and to compare it with column A. I have tried several things but unsuccessfully.

Then I want to compare column C **y1988_12** with part of column B IvanIvanov_32_**y1988_12**.

DBMS MariaDB

Thank you in advance for the help.

Table representation:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IvanIvanov | IvanIvanov_32_y1988_12 | y1988_12 |

Comment: "I have tried several things but unsuccessfully." - So please show your current code and describe what is "unsuccessful" with it.

Comment: Honestly, just does not work. I tried with substring_index but I guess I am not using it correctly.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? As answer can heavily depend on the DBMS you should always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Doesn't work is not what can help us to help you. Because the code that doesn't exist or when your computer is turned off are "doesn't work" also. Please, show your attempt and post the error message you receive. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I am sorry it is MariaDB.

Comment: Okay, I've added the tag for you.

Answer (score 0):

You wonder how to extract the two substrings from B. You don't have to. You merely want to know whether B starts or ends with the substrings A and C. The easiest aproach here is probably `LIKE`. I am assuming your DBMS is MySQL or MariaDB for the mentioned function `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.

With MySQL's `CONCAT` function:

```
select
  b like concat(a, '%') as b_starts_with_a,
  b like concat('%', c) as b_ends_with_c
from mytable;
```

Or with the standard SQL concatenation operator:

```
select
  b like a || '%' as b_starts_with_a,
  b like '%' || c as b_ends_with_c
from mytable;
```

This gives you true / 1 in case of a match and false / 0 in case of a mismatch

Comment: That one seems to work fine. Thank you and I am sorry for the missing DBMS in my first  comment.

Comment: Thanks to @Thorsten Kettner the sql query works fine. Only one more thing. If there is a mismatch shows all rows, e.g. in column A missing a letter. Can I use ID column in the same query in order to show/select the specific row?

Comment: Of course you can select all columns of the table. What keeps you from doing so? Just add them to the `SELECT` clause. You can also restrict the selected rows to mismatches: `select * from mytable where b not like concat(a, '%') or b not like concat('%', c);`.

Comment: I did so but if there is a missing letter e.g. 'i'  in column A, row 1, then I receive a message for a mismatch for the three rows not only for the first one. Here comes the ID column which I want to use somehow for additional "filter" in the same query in order to be left the first row only.

I am sorry if I am bothering you, and one more time thank you :)

Comment: I don't understand. There are many rows with mismatches, but you want to show only one of them? Please edit your request and extend the sample table to show more rows than just one and then add the expected result as a table, too. Thus we may see which rows you want to show in your result and which not.